# Can I speed up nested async/await aiohttp code?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, aiohttp

If I change `in range(1)` to `in range(5)` in code below, it takes about 5 times longer to run. I was hoping to get better numbers from concurrency. Have I set this code up incorrectly?

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp

async def fetch(session):
    async with session.get("http://www.example.com") as res:
        await res.text()

async def foo(session):
    for i in range(10):
        await fetch(session)

async def main(loop):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop = loop) as session:
        for i in range(1):
            await foo(session)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
```

Comment: Maybe you should try to create a list of tasks instead of one loop? And asynchronous is not concurrency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your are looking for is [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) it allows to run several coroutines in parallel.

You will end up with a code that looks like the following

```
def main():
    # init session
    coroutines = list()
    for i in range(5):
        coroutine = fetch(session)  # XXX: mind the fact that there is no await keyword here
        coroutines.append(coroutine)
    await asyncio.gather(*coroutines)
```